# Creating a virtual NIC on windows 7

Tags: networking

How to create a virtual NIC on Windows 7 ? I need the Device Drivers for installing the Virtual NIC that can be listed in Device Manager.

When Enabled it should connect to the same computer. I want to share my internet connection on this virtual LAN and then use it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Under *`hdwwiz.exe` - ... - Select from list - Network Adapters*, you should have a **"Microsoft Loopback Adapter"** device.

- Microsoft Knowledge Base: [How to install the Microsoft Loopback adapter in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839013)
- [How to install a Loopback Adapter in Windows 7](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-7/how-to-install-a-loopback-adapter-in-windows-7/)

Comment: note: in windows 8 it's named "Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter", source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2777200

Comment: On Windows 10 it's also under Network Adapters > choose Microsoft under Manufacturers > choose under Model "Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter"

Answer (score 10):

- First go to 'My computer'
- Right click & go to 'Manage'
- 'Device manager' & right click 'Add legacy hardware'
- Press 'Next'
- Choose second 'Setup manually'
- Then find 'Network Adapter' & 'Next'
- 'Microsoft' or select the 'Loopback' adapter
- Press 'Next'

The virtual loopback adapter is configured your System.