# How can I create a Win7 virtual network connected to my main network?

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-adapter

### Background

I have multiple internet connections which I would love to combine to a single very fast connection. Before trying to setup my own VPN service I stumbled across [Speedify](http://speedify.com). That sounds like it could spare me a lot of setup and up-keep efforts. However I only have a single network card installed and I just have multiple routers with different IPs in my local network (usually I switch the default gateway depending on which uplink I want to use). However Speedify seems to work device based and instead of just entering the gateway IPs I need to have one network card for each uplink (sounds kind of awkward to me, but if it works...).

### Question

How can I (on Win7) create virtual network cards which all behave like they are connected to my main network but which all have a different gateway?

### What I have tried

The question [Creating a virtual NIC on windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/339465/creating-a-virtual-nic-on-windows-7) explains how I can create a virtual network card. I can also assign an IP configuration, but naturally this network card is not really connected to my network. I thought that maybe I can "bridge" the two adapters. In my understanding "bridging" is the same what a switch does. But from the effect I see if I "bridge" two devices in Windows it looks more like bonding (a new device is created which has a new IP address and the two "bridged" devices loose any individual configuration (the menu to configure IP addresses etc is just gone)).

(Note that I am much more experienced in using Linux than Windows. However this is specifically a Windows question).

Comment: You don't need different network interfaces - you just need different IP/SNM/GW tuples.

Comment: @EugenRieck: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Did you [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8944860/1025421)?