# how to run internet & Intranet with one cable in windows 7

Tags: networking, dns

My Internet link is :

```
IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.5
IPv4 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
IPv4 Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
IPv4 DHCP Server: 192.168.1.1
IPv4 DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
```

My Intranet link is :

```
IPv4 Address: 10.161.0.3
IPv4 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
IPv4 Default Gateway: 10.161.0.1
IPv4 DHCP Server: 10.251.33.80
IPv4 DNS Server: 10.251.33.90
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Make 10.161.0.1 a non-default gateway?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to create a virtual NIC (network interface card) on your computer. That way, you'll be able to setup two different connections, while all packets uses the same hardware.

Have a look at this => [Creating a virtual NIC on windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/339465/creating-a-virtual-nic-on-windows-7)